# React Material-UI menu anchor broken by react-window list

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-UI and react-window in a project. My issue is, the material-ui menu component does not anchor to the element provided when that element is within a react-window virtualized list. The menu will appear in the upper left corner of the screen instead of anchored to the button that opens it. When using it all in a non-virtualized list, it works as expected. The menu properly anchors to the button that opens it.

[Here's an example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/3q87l07mlm?fontsize=14). The sandbox is pretty specific to how I'm using the components in question.

Any guidance on how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a modified version of your sandbox that fixes this:

[image: Edit BigList menu]

Here was your initial code in `BigList`:

```
const BigList = props => {
  const { height, ...others } = props;
  const importantData = Array(101 - 1)
    .fill()
    .map((_, idx) => 0 + idx);
  const rows = ({ index, style }) => (
    <FancyListItem
      index={index}
      styles={style}
      text="window'd (virtual): "
      {...others}
    />
  );

  return (
    <FixedSizeList
      height={height}
      itemCount={importantData.length}
      itemSize={46}
      outerElementType={List}
    >
      {rows}
    </FixedSizeList>
  );
};
```

I changed this to the following:

```
const Row = ({ data, index, style }) => {
  return (
    <FancyListItem
      index={index}
      styles={style}
      text="window'd (virtual): "
      {...data}
    />
  );
};

const BigList = props => {
  const { height, ...others } = props;
  const importantData = Array(101 - 1)
    .fill()
    .map((_, idx) => 0 + idx);
  return (
    <FixedSizeList
      height={height}
      itemCount={importantData.length}
      itemSize={46}
      outerElementType={List}
      itemData={others}
    >
      {Row}
    </FixedSizeList>
  );
};
```

The important difference is that `Row` is now a consistent component type rather than being redefined with every render of `BigList`. With your initial code, every render of `BigList` caused all of the `FancyListItem` elements to be remounted rather than just rerendered because the function around it representing the "row" type was a new function with each rendering of `BigList`. One effect of this is that the anchor element you were passing to `Menu` was no longer mounted by the time `Menu` tried to determine its position and anchorEl.getBoundingClientRect() was providing an x,y position of 0,0.

You'll notice in the react-window documentation (https://react-window.now.sh/#/examples/list/fixed-size) the `Row` component is defined outside of the `Example` component similar to how the fixed version of your code is now structured.

Comment: That's a really helpful answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ryan thanks for your answer! It helped me!

There is another solution:
Defining the parent component as a class component (not a functional component).

My problem was that I was calling the 'Rows' function like so:

```
 <FixedSizeList
     height={height}
     itemCount={nodes.length}
     itemSize={50}
     width={width}
     overscanCount={10}
    >
        {({ index, style }) => this.renderListItem(nodes[index], style)}
    </FixedSizeList>
```

The fix was similar to what Ryan suggested:

```
render() {
 ...
 return <FixedSizeList
     height={height}
     itemCount={nodes.length}
     itemSize={50}
     width={width}
     overscanCount={10}
     itemData={nodes}
    >
        {this.renderListItem}
    </FixedSizeList>
  }

  renderListItem = ({data,index, style}) => {
    ...
  }
```

I used the `itemData` prop to access the `nodes` array inside the `renderListItem` function