# React/MUI Popover positioning incorrectly with anchorPosition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-window

I'm using a React/MUI Popover inside a [react-window](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window) List element and am unable to get the Popover to position correctly -- it always winds up in the top left corner of the window (the component is unable to perform a getBoundingClientRctd() on the anchor element [`anchorEl` in the docs]).

So to get around that problem temporarily, I decided to use the `anchorPosition` parameter which allows to set an absolute position -- in my case, just the middle of the window. That's not working either.

I've reviewed the values in Chrome DevTools and everything seems to be OK (i.e., I do get an anchorEl when I'm using that; I get valid positionLeft/Top values; etc...

Probably something really simple and hoping someone can point out what I did wrong.

**Edited: Key elements of the solution**

1. `Row` component must be defined outside of the containing component.
2. the `<List>` component has an `itemData` attribute which is used to pass custom data to `Row`.

**Edited to add react-window List renderer.**

Here's the basic setup:

#### Popover renderer

```
  renderPopover(template, itemId) {
    const { anchorEl, anchorId } = this.state;
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const open = Boolean(anchorEl) && anchorId === itemId;
    const bgColor = '#babaef';
    const { innerHeight, innerWidth } = window;
    const positionLeft = innerWidth / 2;
    const positionTop = innerHeight / 2;
    console.log(`renderPopover: ${positionLeft} / ${positionTop}`);
      <Popover
        id="simple-popper"
        open={open}
        style={{ color: 'Black' }}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={event => this.handlePopoverClose(event)}
        anchorPosition={{ left: {positionLeft}, top: {positionTop} }}
        anchorReference="anchorPosition"
      >
        <Typography style={{ backgroundColor: bgColor }} className={classes.typography}>
          {this.renderScheduleElements(template, itemId)}
        </Typography>
      </Popover>
    );
  }
```

#### Button element renderer

```
 renderScheduleComponent(template, itemId) {
    const { anchorEl, anchorId } = this.state;
    const open = Boolean(anchorEl) && anchorId === itemId;
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const id = open ? 'simple-popper' : undefined;
    return (
      <Grid key={itemId} item>
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>
          <div style={{ padding: '4px' }}>
            <Button
              NO_ref={itemId}
              NODE_ref={(node) => this.buttonRef = node}
              id={itemId}
              name={itemId}
              aria-owns={id}
              aria-haspopup="true"
              variant="outlined"
              color="primary"
              style={{
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                padding: '8px',
                margin: 'auto',
                display: 'block',
                width: '100%',
              }}
              onClick={event => this.handlePopoverClick(event, itemId)}
            >
              {template.templateName}
            </Button>
            {(this.renderPopover).call(this, template, itemId)}
          </div>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
```

#### Click event handler

```
  handlePopoverClick(event, id) {
  event.preventDefault();
    console.log(`handlePopoverClick : ${event.currentTarget.name}`);
    this.setState({
      anchorEl: event.currentTarget,
      anchorId: id,
    });
  }
```

#### react-window List renderer

```
  renderScheduleColumn(columnData) {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { scheduleDate, scheduleTemplates } = columnData;
    this.scheduleTemplates = scheduleTemplates;

    const Row = ({ index, style }) => {
      return (
        <div className={index % 2 ? "ListItemOdd" : "ListItemEven"} style={style}>
          {this.renderScheduleComponent(scheduleTemplates[index], `${scheduleDate}:${index}`)}
        </div>
      );
    }

    const { columnHeight, columnWidth } = this.state;
    return (
      <Grid id={scheduleDate} key={scheduleDate} item>
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>
          <div style={{ width: '100%', textAlign: 'center' }}>
            <Typography variant="h6" style={{ padding: '24px', color: 'white', backgroundColor: '#3f51b5' }}>
              {scheduleDate}
            </Typography>
          </div>
          <List
            className="List"
            height={columnHeight}
            itemCount={scheduleTemplates.length}
            itemSize={50}
            width={columnWidth}
          >
            {Row}
          </List>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Awesome --- that's exactly correct. Thanks much; post an answer so I can give you credit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a similar problem as here: [React Material-UI menu anchor broken by react-window list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55192935/react-material-ui-menu-anchor-broken-by-react-window-list/55203218#55203218).

You should move the definition of your `Row` function out of `renderScheduleColumn` so that it is a consistent type. This will require moving/reworking `renderScheduleComponent` as well. You can use the itemData property on the List to pass information to the Row.