# React Material-UI menu anchor lost because of re-rendered by react-window

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-window

I'm building an infinite loading list of users with [react-window](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window). In the list, every item has an [icon button](https://material-ui.com/api/icon-button/) from Material-UI for further action.
But I can't mount the menu near the icon as the icon button would be re-rendered when setting `anchorEl` for the menu to be opened. A gif clip:

[image: Recording]

The question is related to [React Material-UI menu anchor broken by react-window list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55192935/react-material-ui-menu-anchor-broken-by-react-window-list) but has more HOC. The code is listed [here](https://github.com/ulfjen/SMEIoT/blob/cf3f4f69cd0908495d62d7eec6be5424021bfe24/src/ClientApp/src/dashboard/DashboardUsers.tsx#L203-L237). I wish I could use my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-elion-lkg93) for demonstration but the `react-measure` keeps growing height.

```js
function App() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

  const openMenu = React.useCallback(e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setAnchorEl(e.currentTarget);
    console.log("target", e.currentTarget);
  }, []);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);
  const isItemLoaded = index => {
    const c = index < items.length;
    // console.log("isItemLoaded", index, c);
    return c;
  };
  const loadMoreItems = (startIndex, stopIndex) => {
    console.log("loadMoreItems", startIndex, items);
    setItems(items.concat(Array(10).fill({ name: "1", size: startIndex })));
  };

  const innerET = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <div ref={ref} {...props} />
  ));

  const Row = React.useCallback(
    ({ index, style }) => {
      console.log("Row", items, index);
      return items[index] ? (
        <ListItem style={style} key={index}>
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={openMenu}>
            Row {index}: {items[index].size}
          </Button>
        </ListItem>
      ) : null;
    },
    [items, openMenu]
  );

  const innerListType = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <List ref={ref} {...props} />
  ));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="ceiling">Something at top</div>

      <div className="interest">
        <Menu anchorEl={anchorEl} onClose={handleClose} />
        <Measure bounds offset>
          {({ measureRef, contentRect }) => {
            const height = Math.min(
              contentRect && contentRect.offset
                ? document.getElementById("root").getBoundingClientRect()
                    .height - contentRect.offset.top
                : itemSize * items.length,
              itemSize * items.length
            );
            console.log(
              "bounds",
              height,
              contentRect.bounds,
              contentRect.offset
            );
            return (
              <div>
                <div />
                <div ref={measureRef} className="measurement">
                  <InfiniteLoader
                    isItemLoaded={isItemLoaded}
                    itemCount={itemCount}
                    loadMoreItems={loadMoreItems}
                  >
                    {({ onItemsRendered, ref }) => (
                      <FixedSizeList
                        height={height}
                        width={
                          contentRect.bounds !== undefined &&
                          contentRect.bounds.width !== undefined
                            ? contentRect.bounds.width
                            : -1
                        }
                        itemCount={itemCount}
                        itemSize={itemSize}
                        onItemsRendered={onItemsRendered}
                        ref={ref}
                        innerElementType={innerET}
                      >
                        {Row}
                      </FixedSizeList>
                    )}
                  </InfiniteLoader>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          }}
        </Measure>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As far as I understand, the ripple effect would trigger a re-render in the box with the first click. Moreover, the second click after the re-render upon clicking would not trigger a re-render. That feels even more peculiar to me.

EDIT: I fixed the first sandbox. And by using Material UI's list, this issue is reproducible. https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-butterfly-qn3g7
So the problem lies in using `innerElementType` property.

Comment: I recommend you put more work into creating a sandbox that reproduces your problem. Once you have that, include the relevant code in your question text (in addition to providing the sandbox).

Comment: @RyanCogswell Sandbox and code added. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that a hook is needed.

```js
  const innerListType = React.useMemo(() => {
    return React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
      <List component="div" ref={ref} {...props} />
    ));
  }, []);
```

To fix my problems, hooks for handling events are needed to be handled more carefully.